# How to print out all array in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have managed to print out one array but how to do print out all arrays as this is for forum.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var comments = document.getElementById("allcomments").value; 

     //Get Storage 
                var username = window.localStorage.getItem("username");

        // Call Ajax for existing comments
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'URL',
        success: function(result) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(result);

            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var obj = arr[i];

                console.log(obj);   

                var output = document.getElementById("allcomments"); 
                output.innerHTML = (obj.username + ' ' + obj.comment + ' ' + obj.commDate + ' ' + obj.sentiment); 

            }

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Just don't overwrite the content of `output` with `output.innerHTML = ...`. Append ("add") it to the existing content.

Comment: In other words, use `output.innerHTML += ...` :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Any ideas on how I now go about styling each comment so they appear in blocks more like a forum?

Comment: Wrap them in elements and style those.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am a bit confused on how to do that. As all the array comments are printing out with all comments so I want to get each element in the array. So how do I wrap a div and class around them? inside the js file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you should consider using the `append()` function instead of innerHTML. There are not a lot of valid use cases for innerHTML, you should try to avoid it.

Comment: There are *lots* of valid use cases for `innerHTML`. For example, with templating systems that produce text output.

Comment: Anyone know how I would go about style each element in the array?

Comment: Its not that is not valid, but its not a good practice - calling innerHTML will cause the browser to recreate the DOM which can lead to performance issues.

Comment: @user13382159, yes, just insert a div with classes, and target the classes in your css file. Something like this:

``` output.appendChild(`<div class="my-element" > ${obj.username}  ${obj.comment} ${obj.commDate}  ${obj.sentiment}</div>`);```